# A nonidentity permutation $\sigma$ satisfies $\sigma(i)<i$ for some $i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, permutations

If a permutation $\sigma: N\to N$ is not the identity,  prove that there exists an $i \in \{1,...,n\} $ such that $\sigma(i)<i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove that if $\sigma(i)\geq i$ for all $i$, then $\sigma$ is the identity. We do this by induction on $n$. Clearly it is true if $n=1$. Otherwise, note that $\sigma(n)\geq n$, hence $\sigma(n)=n$ since $n$ is the largest element. Then $\sigma$ restricted to $[n-1]$ is a permutation with the same property on the smaller set, hence is the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the contrary,  that $\sigma (i)\ge i\,,\forall i$.  Then there is a minimum  $\hat i$ for which $\sigma (\hat i)\gt\hat i$.  Now the only remaining choices for $\sigma ^{-1}(\hat i)$ are all greater than $\hat i$.  So if $\sigma (k)=\hat i$, then  $k\gt\sigma (k)$.